# Silhouette Index for selecting a proper number of clusters in KMeans clustering

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using a Silhouette Index for selecting a proper number of clusters in KMeans clustering. The code of the Silhouette Index is given [here](http://code.google.com/p/cluster-algorithms-java-alpha/source/browse/tags/rewritepending/src/validationIndices/SilhouetteIndex.java?r=6). 
Based on this code, I created my own code (see below). The problem is that for any data set the preferred number of clusters is always equal to the maximum, i.e. in this case 15.
Is there any error in my code?

```
private double getSilhouetteIndex(double[][] distanceMatrix,ClusterEvaluation ceval)
{
    double si_index = 0;
    double[] ca = ceval.getClusterAssignments();
    double[] d_arr = new double[ca.length];
    List<Double> si_indexes = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for (int i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
    {
        // STEP 1. Compute the average distance between the i-th point and all other points of a given cluster
        double a = averageDist(distanceMatrix,ca,i,1);

        // STEP 2. Compute the average distance between the i-th point and all points of other clusters
        for (int j=0; j<ca.length; j++)
        {
            double d = averageDist(distanceMatrix,ca,j,2);
            d_arr[j] = d;
        }

        // STEP 3. Compute the the distance from the i-th point to the nearest cluster to which it does not belong
        double b = d_arr[0];
        for (Double _d : d_arr)
        {
            if (_d < b)
                b = _d;
        }

        // STEP 4. Compute the Silhouette index for the i-th point
        double si = (b - a)/Math.max(a,b);

        si_indexes.add(si);
    }

    // STEP 5. Compute the average index over all observations
    double sum = 0;
    for(Double _si : si_indexes)
    {
         sum += _si;
    }
    si_index = sum/si_indexes.size();

    return si_index;
}

private double averageDist(double[][] distanceMatrix, double[] ca, int id, int calc)
{       
    double avgDist = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int len = 0;

    // Distances inside the cluster
    if (calc == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<ca.length; i++)
        {
            if (ca[i] == ca[id] && i != id)
            {
                sum += distanceMatrix[id][i];
                len++;
            }
        }
    }
    // Distances outside the cluster
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<ca.length; i++)
        {
            if (ca[i] != ca[id] && i != id)
            {
                sum += distanceMatrix[id][i];
                len++;
            }
        }
    }

    avgDist = sum/len;

    return avgDist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Silhouette Index, as far as I know, when you calculate avg distance with points outside the cluster, it actually should be`the points from the nearest neighbor cluster` and NOT all the points outside its cluster.

Comment: What defines "nearest neighbour cluster"?  Is it nearest by centroid, data vector closest to centroid or two closest boundary vectors?  The ORIGINAL code searches for closest boundary vectors across all clusters and therefore the logic appears to be correct.